# UserDefault Won't save data in tableView Swift 4

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, swift4

I have been trying to save data when reloading app. However some how data won't save.

```
my global variable

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
```

this is my code on AddTaskView

```
@IBAction func addTask(_ sender: Any) {

    let date = datePicker.date

    let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    taskArray.append(selectedTask)
    dateArray.append(dateStr)

    defaults.set(selectedTask, forKey: "task")
    defaults.set(dateStr, forKey: "date")

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In my ViewController I have my viewWillApper

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    defaults.string(forKey: "task")
    defaults.string(forKey: "date")

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

If I print the data coming back from AddTaskView It will print on console
but data disappear when reloading app

```
tableView.dataSource = self (saved in my viewDidLoad)
```

this is my tableView

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1). \(taskArray[indexPath.row])"

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

What Am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: `UserDefaults` is the wrong place to share data between controllers. Use callback closure or protocol / delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while but I finally figured

```
@IBAction func addTask(_ sender: Any) {

    let date = datePicker.date

    let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    taskArray.append(selectedTask)
    dateArray.append(dateStr)

    defaults.set(taskArray, forKey: "task")
    defaults.set(dateArray, forKey: "date")
    defaults.synchronize()

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func loadUserDefaults() {
    if let tempStr = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "task") {



        taskArray = tempStr as [String]

    }

    if let tempDateStr = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "date") {



        dateArray = tempDateStr as [String]

    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    loadUserDefaults()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple checks to do:

1. `defaults.string(forKey: "task")` has a return value that you dont use
2. As you append entered data, check if its has been append.
3. If entered value is there, check count of rows of the table.

I believe the key to solve your problem is in one of these points.

Comment: defaults.string(forKey: "task") if I print return value added. I don't understand the third option. my numberOfRowsInSection return taskArray.count

Comment: Well you return taskArray.count but you display dateArray. So you have to check dateArray too.

Comment: yes cellForRowAt cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateArray[indexPath.row]

Comment: There is no way that you have the count and data right, and still no data appears. Can you share the code?

Comment: I do, that's my code on top. something is wrong, can't figure out